# In $\Delta ABC$ where $\angle A = 60^\circ$, $BP$ and $BE$ trisect $\angle ABC$ and $CP$ and $CE$ trisect $\angle ACB$ . Find $\angle BPE$ .

Tags: geometry, triangles, problem-solving

> In $\Delta ABC$ where $\angle A = 60^\circ$, $BP$ and $BE$ trisect $\angle ABC$ and $CP$ and $CE$ trisect $\angle ACB$ . Find $\angle BPE$.

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

It is not hard to realise that angle-chasing is useful here, and that's exactly the same thing I did. I got the required angles in the picture as shown, but I can't seem to understand how to get $\angle BPE$ once I join the line $PE$ , if there is no suitable idea other than angle-chasing which I can use here, what should I do?

Can anyone help me? Thank You.

**Edit**: I become a bit stupid sometimes, hence I didn't realise $E$ is the incenter which makes $PE$ the angle bisector, implying $\angle BPE = 50^\circ$.

Comment: The problem can be attacked **very invalidly** through **meta-cheating**.  As you determined, since $3x + 3y = (180 - 60) = 120, 2x + 2y = 80 \implies \angle BPC$ is $100^{\circ}.$  All of the information is **symmetric** about the points $B$ and $C$.  Therefore, without knowing anything about Geometry, there are only two possibilities:  (1) The problem is not well defined. (2) The answer is $100^{\circ} \div 2 = 50^{\circ}.$.  I am not saying that you should use Meta-Cheat'g to solve it.  Only use the Meta-Cheat'g to realize that if the problem is well defined, no **other** answer is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** Note that $BE$ and $CE$ are two of the angle bisectors of $\Delta BPC$, so where is the third one?

Comment: So you mean $PE$ is the $3$rd angle bisector? How will you show it?

Comment: Do you know the term "incenter"?

Comment: I already do, $E$ is the incenter. Nvm I got it.

Comment: Yes, that's right. And we know that incenter is the point at which angle bisectors of a triangle intersect.

Answer (score 2):

as :E is the incenter of $\Delta PEC$  therefore $PE$ bisects the angle

Comment: Oh got it, oof I become a bit dumb sometimes.